# qt applications not running

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, mingw

I have a 32bit windows running mingw32 and Qt 4.8.5.

I have compiled a project with the following commands:

```
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

It loads a second after starting, and then a windows crashed message comes. This shows me that the fault module name is QtCore4.dll - so there seems to be a problem with those dll files.

I also have tried to copy all the dll files from C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin\ to my project's release folder, but it is still the same error.

Comment: What is the error message that you see?

Comment: None, except for "test.exe has crashed"

Answer (score 2):

Download Qt Creator, open the project file in there (the `*.pro` file), build the project and then run it in the debugger. It will tell you where it crashed exactly.

Comment: The debugger  says it stoped after receive of signal from operating system - signal was "sigsegv"

Comment: @PDev The debugger also gives you a backtrace where you can find out where the crash originated in your own program

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a SIGSEGV signal, that's means a Segmentation Fault. Debug to get the exactly line of code where your program crashes. Usually happens when you don't manipulate pointers properly, like go outside an array boundary or access data through a invalid pointer (for example, a pointer that was previously deleted or that points to nullptr).
**Example 1**
`int someArray[50];`
`someArray[100] = 5; /* segmentation fault, index 100 is beyond array boundary */`

**Example 2**
`int *numberPtr = new int(5);`
`*numberPtr = 3; /* it's OK */`
`delete numberPtr; /* invalid pointer. you must not access it anymore */`
`*numberPtr = 3; /* segmentation fault, acceding an invalid pointer */`